# How to split string into characters but to keep spaces in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to split the string into letters and keep space in previous letter.
For example I have this string "Lo ip som." and I want to get this result ['L', 'o ', 'i', 'p ', 's', 'o', 'm', '.']. The 'o ' have space and the 'p ' has space.

Comment: what if there is 2 spaces after letter?

Comment: i will have 'o' and two spaces in same string

Answer (score 2):

```
"Lo ip som.".trim().split('').map(function (ch, i, array) { return ch == ' ' ? array[i - 1] + ' ' : ch })
```

Comment: if you have more than one space between two letter you must call after trim:   .replace(/\s+/gm, ' ')

Answer (score 1):

```
function splitString(str){
    str = str.trim();
    var length = str.length;
    retArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(str[i] === ' '){
           retArr[retArr.length - 1] += ' ';
           continue;
        }
        retArr.push(str[i]);
    }
    return retArr;                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
var str = "Lo ip som.",
    arr = Array.prototype.reduce.call(str,(p,c) => c == " " ? (p[p.length-1]+=" ",p) : p.concat(c),[]);
    document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr) + "</pre>");
```